# Automatic completion for the argument of a bash script

Tags: bash, hostname, auto-completion

I wrote a bash script having one argument, the name of one of the computers connected on my local network. I would like to enable the automatic completion, like I can with ssh. How can I do that ? There is a package called bash-completion, which is installed.

Answer (score 3):

If your command is named `foo`, apply the same `complete` function used for `ssh` to it:

```
$ complete -p ssh
complete -F _ssh ssh
$ complete -F _ssh echo
$ echo 192.168.<tab>
192.168.0.107  192.168.0.118  192.168.0.98
```